# Create a CSV feed from a Model MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, csv

I have an ICollection of a Model that I need to pick certain fields from the Model and create a CSV file from the Model.  Right now I am doing a foreach through the model and pulling fields and just contatinating them like so:

```
foreach(OrderComposite ord in orders)
{
   order += ord.Customer.EmailAddress.ToString() + "," + ord.OrderId.Value.ToString() + "," + ord.DateCreated.Value.ToString() + "," + ord.TotalSalePrice.Value.ToString() + "," + ord.TotalSaleTax.Value.ToString() + ",0,0," + ord.OrderStatus.ToString() + ",?,?,?,?" + ord.TotalDiscount.Value.ToString() + ",online";
}
```

This is not how I want to do this.  I am sure there is a way to do this via LINQ but I am having problems getting the Order.Select statement working. I know using this method would be extremely inefficient, so I started trying this:

```
using(var file = File.CreateText(settings.listrakProductFeed.ListrakOrderItemsFileLocation))
{
   file.WriteLine(orders.Select(x => string.Join(",",x.Customer.EmailAddress.ToString(), x.OrderId.Value.ToString())));
}
```

Is this more efficient?  Ultimately I will use WriteLineAsync, but one step at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this more efficient then what? Also using `.Select` is almost the same as the `foreach` for in memory collection and only slightly less efficient - nothing to really be concerned of in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very naive implementation of a delimited file result

```
public enum DelimitedFileHeaderOptions
{
    IncludeHeader,
    DoNotIncludeHeader
}

public class DelimitedFileResult<T> : FileResult where T : class
{
    private const String DefaultFileName = "file.csv";
    private const String DefaultContentType = "text/csv";
    private const String DefaultDelimiter = ",";

    public DelimitedFileResult(IEnumerable<T> data, DelimitedFileHeaderOptions headerOption)
        : this(data, DefaultDelimiter, DefaultFileName, DefaultContentType, headerOption) { }

    public DelimitedFileResult(IEnumerable<T> data, String delimiter = DefaultDelimiter, String fileName = DefaultFileName, String contentType = DefaultContentType,
        DelimitedFileHeaderOptions headerOption = DelimitedFileHeaderOptions.IncludeHeader)
        : base(contentType)
    {
        _data = data;
        _delimiter = delimiter;
        FileDownloadName = fileName;
        _headerOption = headerOption;
    }

    protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        var properties = (from p in typeof (T).GetProperties() select p).ToList();
        var propertyNames = (from p in properties select p.GetDisplayName()).ToList();

        if (_headerOption == DelimitedFileHeaderOptions.IncludeHeader)
            builder.AppendLine(String.Join(_delimiter, propertyNames));

        foreach (T item in _data)
        {
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                builder.Append(property.GetValue(item, null));
                builder.Append(_delimiter);
            }

            builder.AppendLine();
        }

        response.Write(builder.ToString());
    }

    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _data;
    private readonly String _delimiter;
    private readonly DelimitedFileHeaderOptions _headerOption;
}
```

1. Create a class with the fields you want in the csv file.
2. run your linq query
3. pass the resulting IEnumerable to the constructor

Things it doesn't do.

Handle string with the delimiter in the property values.
nested types.  you are expected to flatten the data yourself.

but those are certainly things you could add yourself.